# How to intercept execution of a perl script using a shell script and then actually execute them?

Tags: linux, bash, perl, shell

The question is a bit complicated, first I'm going to put you in situation.
I have a web server with many domains and I want to know which perl scripts run the users in each domain and with which parameters.

For this I thought of renaming the perl, and create a script that is called perl that saves in a log the environment and then execute the script in perl

The script is very simple, but obviusly have something wrong

```
#!/bin/sh 

when=`date "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`
log_file="/var/logs/perl/${when}"
env > log_file
parameters=$@
echo "Parameters: $parameters" >> $log_file
/usr/local/bin/perl_bin $parameters
```

I use a simple perl script to test:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Working\n\n";
```

Now, the problem
If I run the perl script from the shell like this:

## perl script.pl

Works Ok

But If I run the perl script from the shell like this:

## ./script.pl

Don´t works and the error looks:

./script.pl: line 3: print: command not found

What am I missing ?

Comment: *"I want to know which perl scripts run the users in each domain and with which parameters"* This seems like something your webserver probably already records in its logs. Which webserver are you using? (e.g. Apache, nginx)

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in the comments, this is probably overkill for your purposes and you risk subtly breaking every Perl program on your server (for example, you're passing parameters incorrectly). You're better off using your server logs or something at the kernel level like `lsof`. Or ask yourself why you need to know which programs your users are running at all.

But it's handy to understand what's going on.

---

***The program in `#!` must be a compiled executable. It cannot be interpreted.*** For example...

```
$ cat /Users/schwern/tmp/notperl 
#!/bin/sh

perl "$@"

$ cat /Users/schwern/tmp/test.pl 
#!/Users/schwern/tmp/notperl

print "Hello, world!\n";

$ /Users/schwern/tmp/notperl /Users/schwern/tmp/test.pl
Hello, world!

$ /Users/schwern/tmp/test.pl
/Users/schwern/tmp/test.pl: line 3: print: command not found
```

What's happening is `test.pl` is executed and the [program loader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loader_(computing)) sees the [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)). It then checks to see if that is an absolute path to an executable program. Not just any executable, but ***one that can be executed by the kernel directly***.

Since `/Users/schwern/tmp/notperl` is interpreted, the kernel ignores the `#!` line and hands it off to the shell to execute. The shell has no `print` function and tells you so.

---

One generally gets around this with `/usr/bin/env`. This is a little program to execute another program in a modified environment. With no options it just executes the program.

```
$ cat /Users/schwern/tmp/test.pl 
#!/usr/bin/env /Users/schwern/tmp/notperl

print "Hello, world!\n";

$ /Users/schwern/tmp/test.pl
Hello, world!
```

In this case the kernel executes `/usr/bin/env` with the argument `/Users/schwern/tmp/notperl`. `/usr/bin/env` then executes `/Users/schwern/tmp/notperl`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation !
I have to lern a lot yet !
The real problem is not what are the user "using", the problem is "what a hacker is using without the knowledge of the user"
I have all the logs, but there is nothing 
Finally, I think that I found from where comes the attack, is not from the web server (Apache), is from Dovecot